# jQuery Toggle Issue - fading divs in and out

Tags: jquery, toggle

Trying to build a simple toggle where someone clicks a list item with an `ID` and it displays a `div` associated with said list item, then on click of a different list item, the first `div` fades out and the new `div` fades in, and obviously should work where if you click `<li id="1">` then `<li id="3">`, then back to 1, it works correctly.

Here's my code thus far.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#list li').toggle(function() {
        var $value = ($(this).attr('id'));
        $('#song' + $value).fadeIn();
    },
    function() {
        $('#song' + $value).fadeOut(); 
        var $value = ($(this).attr('id'));
        $('#song' + $value).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Thanks! matt

Comment: Why do You use $value instead of var value?

Comment: @peri overlooked var.  @neal, it only works for one instance through, i can't click id1, then id2, then back to id1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easier way to fade out the currently visible div is to use the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector. Also, if I understand your question correctly, I think you can achieve the desired behavior just using `.click()` rather than `.toggle()`:

```
$('#list li').click( function() {
  $('#your_container').find('div:visible').fadeOut();
  $('#song' + this.id).fadeIn(); // simpler, no intermediate variable needed
});
```